# MKPinAnnotationView red pin is replaced with image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have replaced the `MKPinAnnotationView` red pin  with an image in

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation  
{
MKAnnotationView *annotationView=[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:parkingAnnotationIdentifier];
//If one isn’t available, create a new one
if(!annotationView){
annotationView=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:parkingAnnotationIdentifier];
//Here’s where the magic happens
annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dot.png"];
}
return annotationView;
}
```

Now i have a detail disclosure when I click on any button it will go to the detailed page of that annotation.

Up to here its fine. Now the problem is that when I come back to the map view again from the detail page the default red pin appears instead of dot.png because when a view is loaded for the first time `-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation` 
 this method is called but when we come back from the detail page view will appear is not getting called. How to resolve this issue?

```
if ([list_array count]>0) {
        location1.latitude = [[[list_array objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"latitude"]floatValue];
        location1.longitude = [[[list_array objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"longitude"]floatValue];
        region.center = location1;

        if ([[list_array objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"company_id"]) {
            for (int i=0; i<[list_array count]; i++) 
            {
                CLLocationCoordinate2D location1;
                location1.latitude = [[[list_array objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"latitude"]floatValue];
                location1.longitude = [[[list_array objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"longitude"]floatValue];
                region.span = span;

                BasicMapAnnotation *addAnnotation1 = [[BasicMapAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:location1.latitude andLongitude:location1.longitude] ; 
                addAnnotation1.tag = i;
                [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation1];
            }
        }
    }

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    //[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
```

Answer (score 1):

just add the whole pins or setRegion in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` method

here `viewForAnnotation` is called again when we `addAnnotation` in `MKMapView` so just call it or also refresh it with `setRegion` method of `MKMapView`.

Or just remove these whole pins and add again in `viewDidAppear:` like bellow....

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSArray *existingpoints = mapView.annotations;
    if ([existingpoints count] > 0)
        [mapView removeAnnotations:existingpoints];

    if ([[list_array objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"company_id"]) {
   for (int i=0; i<[list_array count]; i++) 
   {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location1;
    location1.latitude = [[[list_array objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"latitude"]floatValue];
    location1.longitude = [[[list_array objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"longitude"]floatValue];
    region.span = span;

    BasicMapAnnotation *addAnnotation1 = [[BasicMapAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:location1.latitude andLongitude:location1.longitude] ; 
    addAnnotation1.tag = i;
    [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation1];
    }
}
   [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
   [mapView regionThatFits:region];
}
```

i hope this helpful to you...

Comment: Its not getting called sir.......i have keep  [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

Comment: ok but now i just give the logic which must work perfactly just remove whole annotations(pins) and add these whole pins again in viewDidLoad method.. wait i will update the answer..

Comment: just post the code where you add annotation with method in which you use the code for that

Comment: hey try now this code dude.. just change some code with your requirement and try it and let me know...

Comment: Sir what u have changed sir.. same now sir  have added the code what i laced now sir its not working sir

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22099/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-08442)

Comment: hi please click on above link i just want to ask some flow of your code.. may be i will solve your this problem so..

Comment: @Vishal hi bro, you get problem like that??

Comment: Yes, 6 month back...then I change my idea to add picture in place of pin.

Comment: @Vishal ohhh from Punjab?? wow bro i like that state and also person yaar bahot hi pyare log aur bahot a6e hote he yaar waha k log .. nice.. :)